# Chrome Extension Mute Background Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension, mute

I am opening discord.com/channels/@me in an iframe in the Backgroundpage of my Extension.
Now i want to mute all sound within the BGPage/iframe.

I tried to inject a Script into the iframe and mute all audio/video Tags everytime the MutationObserver found something didnt work(muted = true | volume = 0 | pause()). For some Reason there is no audio/video Tag on the Site and i cant see any in the MutationObserver.

Then i tried to mute the Page via chrome.tabs, but it cant find the BGPage since its not a Tab.

Comment: Are you sure the script ran? Did you declare it in manifest.json with `all_frames`?

Comment: Yes, the script does other things aswell and they work properly. The MutationObserver wouldnt work if it doesnt inject either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is redundant as manifest V3 will take over soon and it doesnt support background pages anymore.

Comment: Can you share where you find that it's not supported ? Like give link to bugs report/ticket/MAJ infos

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/#service-workers Here it says that background pages are not supported anymore.